# Apply two different model matrices to two vertices to draw a line

Tags: opengl

I would like to draw a line between two vertices. But, I don't know the two points in advance.

What I'm trying to do to achieve this is upload a vertex buffer with two vertices at (0, 0, 0). Then, when before the draw call, i.e. before glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 1), try to translate the two vertices with separate model matrices. I'm using a single shader program. To explain it more, it's sort of like I know the fromVertex and toVertex and I want to draw a line them. I want to apply model matrix 1, to translate vertice 1 from (0, 0, 0) to fromVertex, and model matrix 2, to translate vertice 2 from (0, 0, 0) to toVertex.

```
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 model;

in vec3 vert;
in vec2 vertTexCoord;
in vec3 vertColor;

out vec2 fragTexCoord;
out vec3 fragColor;


void main() {
    // Pass the tex coord straight through to the fragment shader
    fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;
    fragColor = vertColor;

    // Apply all matrix transformations to vert
    gl_Position = projection * camera * model * vec4(vert, 1);
}
```

I can't translate this into code, because I can't think of a way to set the model matrix uniform variable in the vertex shader to two different values when drawing a line. I'm trying to think of using a scale and/or rotate operation to achieve this. But, I'm guessing there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Why are you tring to do this at all? (Not saying that it can't be done.) But:  When you apply some matrix M to the point (0,0,0,1), you just select the last column of the matrix - so instead of using the (0,0,0,1) vertex and uploading two matrices, you could upload the resulting vertcies directly.

Comment: `glDrawArrays (GL_LINES, 0, 1)` is not going to do anything, by the way. You need at least two points in your line list to create a line.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this without using glBufferData in the render loop. Just using that and uploading the vertices solves the problem trivially.